# What are the Islamic tenets regarding cemeteries?

Tags: death

I am visiting a village in a Muslim nation.  There is a mosque here.  Right next to the mosque is a cemetery with many graves, some very old and some relatively new.  The cemetery is unmaintained, it seems.  The grass is high, graves are crumbling over, and things are generally in bad condition.  Given that it's right next to a mosque I was surprised to see this, as I assumed (apparently incorrectly?) that it would be the duty of the mosque to maintain it.

Hence the question in the title: what should be done (according to Islam) about this cemetery, especially considering that it's right next to (adjoined to) a mosque>

Comment: Maintenance of Cemetery/Graveyard is not the responsibility of the Mosque, it is the responsibility of the society and especially the relatives of the dead to maintain the cemetery. I think its the carelessness of the people or the village is poor/unable to pay for the maintenance. So a person could donate for the maintenance of the graveyard.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by maintained. In Islam a cemetery must be surrounded by a protective wall that's all what a community must do. As for graves most things for example Christians do are regarded as haram. So as long as the graveyard is clean it is fine.

Comment: @Medi1Saif there is a wall.  But the old graves have crumbled to the ground, but the grass is not cut.  What are some of the things that can't be done since they are haram?

Comment: @HorseHair Read                                                                                                       
[What is the appropriate manner of burial according to Islamic law?](https://www.dar-alifta.org/Foreign/ViewFatwa.aspx?ID=8094)